# Http Post Not Showing Content

Tags: c++, qt

so am trying to post to my `localhost` to get a result if it succeeded or not and I am having a problem. I think it's not sending the request or just not getting the result of the page. I added:

```
QT += network
```

but its still not working

```
void sendPost() {

QEventLoop eventLoop;
QNetworkAccessManager mgr;

QUrlQuery postData;
postData.addQueryItem("unm", "user");
postData.addQueryItem("pwd", "81238as");

QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(QString("http://localhost/login.php")));
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

QNetworkReply *reply = mgr.post(request, postData.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8());
eventLoop.exec();

if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {

    QString data = reply->readAll();
        qDebug(data.toUtf8().constData());
        delete reply;
}
else {
    qDebug() << "Failure" <<reply->errorString();
    delete reply;
  }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run `eventLoop` so it blocks all your app, you should quit from `eventLoop` when your manager is finished. Next code works but to be honest, I always do this with signals and slots so I don't know is usage of `QEventLoop` is correct approach.

Try this:

```
#include <QObject>
//...
QEventLoop eventLoop;
QNetworkAccessManager mgr;

QUrlQuery postData;
postData.addQueryItem("unm", "user");
postData.addQueryItem("pwd", "81238as");

QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(QString("http://localhost/login.php")));
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

QNetworkReply *reply = mgr.post(request, postData.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8());
QObject::connect(&mgr,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),&eventLoop,SLOT(quit()));
eventLoop.exec();

if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {

    QString data = reply->readAll();
        qDebug(data.toUtf8().constData());
        delete reply;
}
else {
    qDebug() << "Failure" <<reply->errorString();
    delete reply;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but am getting this error when i try to run it C3861: 'connect': identifier not found

Comment: Yes i did is that the problem?

Comment: @Shrekt then you should write QObject::connect and include <QObject>. I updated my answer.

Comment: Done No Problem bro do you know how i can do an https i posted for help but no one is giving me an example there just saying its wrong :/  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565666/cannot-retrieve-page-contents-through-https-with-qnetworkaccessmanager?noredirect=1#comment41761447_26565666

Comment: @Shrekt Unfortunately I can't help you here :( I never did post request before. My answer here was right because source of problem was EventLoop, not a specific things from QNetworkAccessManager. Sorry.